# Why is function with protocol as its argument not working with type extensions that conform to the same protocol in Swift?

Tags: swift, types, swift-protocols

I have a protocol `FnProtocol`, which `String` and `Int` conforms to.

```
protocol FnProtocol {

}

extension Int: FnProtocol {

}

extension String: FnProtocol {

}
```

I then created a function `f3` which takes `FnProtocol` as its argument.

```
func f3(_ x: FnProtocol) -> FnProtocol {
    return x
}
```

Next, the `comp` function accepts an array of functions which works on `FnProtocol`.

```
func comp(fns: [(FnProtocol) -> FnProtocol]) -> (FnProtocol) -> FnProtocol {
    return fns[0]
}
```

```
func count(_ s: String) -> Int {
    return s.count
}
```

Considering that `String` and `Int` conforms to `FnProtocol`, why does `comp(fns: [count])` fail but `comp(fns: [f3])` works?

```
comp(fns: [count])  // Cannot convert value of type '(String) -> Int' to expected element type '(FnProtocol) -> FnProtocol'
```

How to get this working with `count`?

Comment: `count` takes a String and not a FnProtocol as argument, not sure why you would expect that implicit cast to work? And s.count only work on String, not on Int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use `count()` it need to take a `FnProtocol` as a parameter

```
func count(_ s: FnProtocol) -> Int {
    return s.count
}
```

Of course this mean we need to modify the protocol and make `Int` adhere to it

```
protocol FnProtocol {
    var count: Int {get}
}

extension Int: FnProtocol {
    var count: Int {
        return String(self).count
    }
}
```